# nested ng-repeat $digest() doesn't update the view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Please,help me to understand how to update view for nested grouped ng-repeats.
suppose I have the following model 
doc has one to many relationship with pages.

in the view I render docs collection and their pages by 3 in row using array of arrays.

in the controller I have method to add page the the doc but it doesn't update the view

any help appreciated. I'll provide code later

UPDATE:
Here's the code in question http://plnkr.co/edit/dGVW0QaUArf0okTJexMv

UPDATE

So, from the code, I must somehow fire grouping update, but I don't know how to achieve that. Is there a way to force angular to check nested collections inside ng-repeat items?

UPDATE: 
  Updated plunk example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in order to workaround aforementioned problem, one must add this lines to controller and update markup. It publishes  groups to the scope and add watchers in loop for every doc in docs collection.

Controller:

```
$scope.docs.forEach(function (itm,idx) {
    $scope.$watch('docs['+idx+'].pages', function (val) {
        $scope.docs[idx].groups = $scope.groupBy(val,3);
        },true);
});
```

View:

```
<tr data-ng-repeat-start='doc in docs' >
    <th>&nbsp</th>
    <th>{{doc.name}}</th>
 </tr>

<tr  data-ng-repeat='group in doc.groups'>

<td data-ng-repeat='page in group'>
    {{page.name}}
 </td>
</tr>
<tr data-ng-repeat-end>
    <td>&nbsp</td>
    <td ><a href='#' data-ng-click = 'addPage(doc)'>addPage</a></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 3):

It would be good to see some code to understand the relationship of what updates what, but try putting

```
 $scope.$apply();
```

in the method in the controller which updates the view.

that may give you an error if a digest cycle is in process, which is good, because it means something is updating.

if so, you can try

```
if(!$scope.$$phase){
  $scope.$apply();
}
```

which will check if a $digest is running on the scope, and if not, it will run it.

Comment: Hi, I've uploaded the simplified version of my code. In my real code I use Breezejs as a factory for pages.

Comment: I've added $scope.$apply(), it throws digest already in progress

Comment: That's a good thing, did you try using $scope.$apply within !!$scope.$$phase? I think what may be happening is that because you are running multiple digests, one might be getting missed, so the code I described will check if a digest is running, and if not, it will run it, if it is, it won't do anything, so you won't get the error.